# Skip RubyGems install in .rvmrc if current version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rvmrc

My `.rvmrc` file's contents are as follows:

```
rvm --install use 1.9.3@my_gemset && rvm rubygems 1.8.6 && gem list
```

Unfortunately, this causes rubygems to reinstall even if my current rubygems version is 1.8.6. It's not a major problem, but a minor annoyance whenever I open a new tab or have to move out of and back into the application's directory.

Is is possible to skip the install if RubyGems is already at the specified version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to check rubygems version:

```
rvm --install --create use 1.9.3@my_gemset &&
{
  [[ "$(gem --version)" =~ 1.8.6 ]] || rvm rubygems 1.8.6
} &&
gem list
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. I didn't know it functioned like a bash script!

Comment: RVM is a bash script and it sources `.rvmrc` - that's why you need to trust this file - any code can be inside.